# MVC Dropdown list getting selected ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an entity, lets say `Person`:

```
class Person
{
    id Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

This RoleId property corresponds to a role selected from a list of available Roles. I pass this list of roles to the view using the ViewData object:

```
List<SelectListItem> roles = new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem(){ Text = "User", Value = "0"},
    new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Admin", Value = "1"}
};
ViewData["roles"] = roles;
```

(Note I use strings as values here as it doesn't let me use integers?)

My View (it's an "add" view, to create a new Person) inherits from the Person entity. I am unsure how to setup the dropdown list in the view so that the value of the selected item in the list gets set as the RoleId property  value in the Person object that is sent back to the Controller (for the HttpPost method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    "RoleId", 
    new SelectList(ViewData["roles"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

This being said it is not a code that I would recommend. Everytime I see someone using ViewData my temperature raises.

I would use view models:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new PersonViewModel
    {
        Roles = new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "User", Value = "0" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Admin", Value = "1" }
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.RoleId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Value", "Text")
) %>
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, the ViewModel method looks a lot cleaner, I'll see about using it instead.

Comment: Darin, is there a reason that SelectListItem doesn't allow int to be set as the value property?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: Andy, to your question about why you can't use an int, it is because HTML doesn't know anything about types, only strings. However, as mentioned below, the MVC model binder will look at the RoleId property (which is an int) and attempt the conversion for you. If you passed say, "one" in there, the model binding would fail.

I think there are two things to understand here:

1. What HTML Html.DropDownList() produces
2. How model binding in MVC works.

First, the call:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDowListId", (List<SelectListItem>)this.ViewData["roles"], "Select a role...")
```

produces:

```
<select id="DropDowListId" name="DropDowListId">
    <option value="">Select a role...</option>
    <option value="0">User</option>
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

This results in a FORM post (assuming name is Joe, and role is Admin) which has the following content:

```
Name=Joe&DropDowListId=1
```

Now, assuming your post method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
```

The model binder can map Name to person, but doesn't know what to do with DropDownListId (it isn't part of the Person model).

So, if you change the name of the DropDownList to the RoleId in your Person class:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId", (List<SelectListItem>)this.ViewData["roles"], "Select a role...")
```

will produce:

```
<select  id="RoleId" name="RoleId">
    <option value="">Select a role...</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="0">User</option>
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
</select>
```

Note, you would actually get extra validation information too (looking like this: data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RoleId must be a number." data-val-required="The RoleId field is required.")

Now, when the post happens, the form will have the following content:

```
Name=Joe&RoleId=1
```

Which the model binder will be able to bind to your class. and Person will now consist of a Name: Joe, RoleId: 1. The string '1' will even be converted to an int (or, if you used a string as a RoleId, it would stay as a string of '1'.

Cool, eh?